# Smoothing of a Kähler orbifold metric on a complex surface

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, orbifolds

Let $S$ be a smooth complex projective surface and $D\subset S$ be a smooth complex curve. Fix an integer $m>1$ and consider $(S,D,m)$ as an orbifold with orbi-locus $D$ with stabilizer $\mathbb Z_m$ along $D$. Suppose now we have a Kähler orbifold metric $\omega$ on $(S,D,m)$ (with metric singularity along $D$). I would like to find a short proof or a reference for the following statement:

**Statement.** For arbitrary small $\varepsilon$-neighborhood $U_{\varepsilon}$ of $D$ in $S$ there is a smooth Kähler metric $\omega_{\varepsilon}$ on $S$  such that $\omega_{\varepsilon}$ coincides with $\omega$ in $S\setminus U_{\varepsilon}$.

**PS.** I will be happy, if the statement is proven in the following situation: $S$ is a ruled surface and $D$ is embedded in $S$ as a holomorphic section (i.e. it intersects all $\mathbb CP^1$-fibers in one point). Moreover if necessary one may assume that the Kähler orbi-metric is invariant under a holomorphic $S^1$-action on $S$ fixing $D$ pointwise.

**PPS.** I also removed the condition on $\omega_{\varepsilon}$ to be in the same cohomology class as $\omega$ (since it turned out to be irrelevant for me).

Comment: Did you try a very nice bump function and averaging? 

What is your definition of "orbi-singularity"?

Comment: I did not try. Orbifold metric is a metric that can be obtained locally as a quotient by isometry. In the particular case that I consider it has the following local model:  Take the ball $B_1$ in $\mathbb C^2$ i.e. $|z^2|+|w^2|\le 1$ take a Kahler metric on it, invariant under the linear $\mathbb Z_m$ action on $B_1$, fixing $z=0$. Take quotient.

Comment: I know the (usual) definition of orbi-fold metric, but what is an "orbi-singularity." I don't know this word. To me, for example, the plane/$\mathbb{\mu}_n$ is smooth. Is that an orbi-singularity though?

Comment: I changed the phrasing. Hope this does not cause confusion anymore.

Comment: Sorry for being pedantic, but I'm not an expect in the field. Does your definition of metric singularity mean that, say, the euclidean plane/$\mu_n$ (act by rotation, flat metric $\overline{g}$) contains a metric singularity? To me this is a smooth Riemannian stack.

Comment: See: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/19530/what-is-meant-by-smooth-orbifold?rq=1

Comment: Arthur, for me the quotient of $\mathbb C$ by a rotation $z\to \mu_n \cdot z$ has a metric singularity. I understand that this also can be seen as a smooth orbifold, but this is not the point of view that I am interested in (in this question). What I am interested in is in the metric on the quotient. You can see this quotient as a smooth surface (in the ordinary sense, not orbi sense or in the sense of a stack) and then you get a sinugular metric on a smooth complex surface that I want to smoothen. If you want, this is about smoothing of conical singularities.

Comment: Got it! That clarifies. Essentially you are just considering a singular metric on the coarse space of the orbifold. And I guess your Kähler class $[\omega]$ is not in some stacky cohomological sense. Now I understand your question. Sorry about the extended confusion.

Comment: I think I can see how to do this, for metrics in rational cohomology classes, but I'm skeptical that the two metrics would have the same K\"{a}hler class.

Comment: Dear Craig, I would be happy to see how you do what you say, could you please write an answer?

Comment: Hassan, unfortunately this does not make much sense for me, can you first do what you say for the 1-dim case, for example for the quotient metric on $\mathbb C^1/\pm 1$

Comment: Theorem 6.2 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0412405.pdf , I read it long times ago , see also https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0411522.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Let $S=S^{sing}\cup S^{reg}$ take  an orbifold resolution $\pi : \tilde S \to S$ with simple normal crossing exceptional divisor $E = \pi^{−1}(S^{sing})$ such that
$\pi$ is an isomorphism over $S^{reg}$. then take $\omega_\epsilon=\pi^*\omega_0-\epsilon\theta_E$ as K\"ahler metric on $\tilde S $ in adiabatic classes(see [Lemma 4.2.3](https://dipot.ulb.ac.be/dspace/bitstream/2013/209324/1/bec8d467-b463-4b7e-955c-0fa0bd312e03.txt) that why such metric $\omega_\epsilon$ is as Kahler metric in fibration case or [Lemma1](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1209.2198.pdf) for resolution case . Here $\omega_0$ is a positive closed $(1,1)$-current on $S$ and $\theta_E$ is a positive closed $(1,1)$-current on $E$)

Consider a smooth geometric orbifold given by $\mathbb Q$-divisor $$D=\sum_{j\in J}(1-\frac{1}{m_j})D_j$$ where $m_j\geq 2$ are positive integers and $\text{Supp}D=\cap_{j\in J}D_j$ is of normal crossings divisor. Let $\omega$ be any K\"ahler metric on $S$, let
$C >0$ be a real number and $s_j\in H^0\left(S,\mathcal O_X(D_j)\right)$ be a section defining $D_j$. Consider the following expression

$$\omega_D=C\omega+\sqrt[]{-1}\sum_{j\in J}\partial\bar\partial |s_j|^{2/m_j}$$

If $C$ is large enough, the above formula defines a closed positive $(1,1)$
-current (smooth away from $D$). Moreover

$$\omega_D\geq \omega$$ in the sense of currents. Consider $\mathbb C^n$ with the orbifold divisor given by the equation

$$\prod_{j=1}^nz_j^{1-{1}/{m_j}}=0$$ (with eventually $m_j=1$ for some $j$). The sections
$s_j$ are simply the coordinates $z_j$ and a simple computation gives

$$\omega_D=\omega_{eucl}+\sqrt[]{-1}\sum_{j=1}^n\partial\bar\partial |z_j|^{2/m_j}=\omega_{eucl}+\sqrt[]{-1}\sum_{j=1}^n\frac{dz_j\wedge d\bar {z_j}}{m_j^2|z_j|^{2(1-1/m_j)}}$$

See paper of 
Frédéric Campana; Mihai Păun
Orbifold generic semi-positivity: an application to families of canonically polarized manifolds
(Semi-positivité orbifolde : une application aux familles de variétés canoniquement polarisées)
Vol. 65 no. 2 (2015), p. 835-861 Details

http://www.numdam.org/article/AIF_2015__65_2_835_0.pdf

Comment: Hassan, $S$ is a smooth complex surface, it has no singularities. Could you please change your answer accordingly? In the line three of your text you write without justification, that $\omega_{\epsilon}$ is Kaher. This does not make sense to me

Comment: Also you don't say what is $\omega_0$, you don't say what is $\theta_E$, etc...

Comment: $\omega_\epsilon$ is Kahler metric in adiabatic classes, I added a reference. It is known fact due to Tian-Yau

Comment: You may see Lemma1 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1209.2198.pdf

Comment: I deleted my previous comment (since it was a bit aggressive)  but I still think that in this answer you don't really address my question but write something (that I can not really understand) on an adjacent topic.